# payment gateway availability expectation/guarantee

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate a payment gateway to my ecommerce website. Should I expect an uptime guarantee from payment gateway? Ideally, I think they should have a monitoring system that can alert me if there are any issues with the gateway (I might integrate with two gateways and I can take one down if it has issues), or is too much to expect? What else should I expect from the payment gateways to facilitate any other issues? (the payment gateway I am talking of doesn't seem to have such enablers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From many of the major payment gateways (Authorize.net, Beanstream, Paypal, etc.), you should expect very good uptime and a monitoring system in place to alert you of issues.

I've worked in ecommerce web development for 5 years. I recall just a couple of of times where Authorize.net went down for a little while. Clients were notified promptly and service restored quickly. When service does goes down, you can bet the big guys customer service lines go crazy (and so does Twitter).